# RecursionError when Accessing Null DecimalField in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model in Django 1.11.2 that has a `DecimalField`. The field is nullable. When accessing the field I get a recursion error for some reason.

```
ipdb> student.current_longitude
*** RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
ipdb>
```

Can this have something to do with the way the null value is being serialized into a `DecimalField`? What's going on here?

```
ipdb> type(student.current_longitude)
*** RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
ipdb>
```

#### Model Definition

```
current_longitude = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, decimal_places=13, max_digits=16)
current_latitude = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, decimal_places=13, max_digits=16)
```

#### UPDATE

There's a mixin with a `__setattr__` that's throwing the exception:

```
def __setattr__(self, key, value):

    if key in ('updated_at',):
        pass

    elif getattr(self, '_initiated', False) and key not in getattr(self, '_non_model_fields', set()):
        try:
            field = self._meta.get_field(key)
        except FieldDoesNotExist:
            self._non_model_fields.add(key)
        else:
            # Foreignkeys may show up twice once as _id and once as the object
            # and for serialization and consistency purposes we only want the _id property
            # so we detect if the field is a FK and it's the FK not ending in _id and exclude it.
            # Also GeopositionField is ignoring because this field raises recursion depth via this mixin
            if isinstance(field, ForeignKey) and key[-3:] != '_id' or isinstance(field, GeopositionField):
                self._non_model_fields.add(key)
            else:
                old_value = getattr(self, key)
                if old_value != value:
                    self._dirty_fields[key] = old_value
```

The exception gets thrown on this line `old_value = getattr(self, key)`. Why is `getattr()` calling the setter?

Comment: Can you post out `type(student.current_longitude)` ?

Comment: @gushitong Same error when I try to get the type

Comment: Can you post the model `Student`?

Comment: @Lemayzeur the model is rather large so I posted the relevant fields that this is happening with. Is there anything else specifically that you wanted to see?

Comment: I copied exactly your models and tested it, no error. maybe this field hasn't the value expected, or some methods try to get access recursively